# Mapping out DOM nodes from React Hooks GET

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, ref

Apologies in advance for not wording my question as well as it could have been.

I followed a MERN tutorial that was all done using  class based React components. I am trying to convert it over to functional components with hooks.

I am having trouble saving the users/usernames from the initial GET request, and then subsequently mapping them out onto a html select form so that the new form submit can be attributed to one of the existing users.

Here is what the tutorial code looks like that functions as intended:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

export default class CreateRide extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDescription = this.onChangeDescription.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDuration = this.onChangeDuration.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDistance = this.onChangeDistance.bind(this);
    this.onChangeDate = this.onChangeDate.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: '',
      description: '',
      duration: 0,
      distance: 0,
      date: new Date(),
      users: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/')
      .then(response => {
        if (response.data.length > 0) {
          this.setState({
            users: response.data.map(user => user.username),
            username: response.data[0].username
          });
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDescription(e) {
    this.setState({
      description: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDuration(e) {
    this.setState({
      duration: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDistance(e) {
    this.setState({
      distance: e.target.value
    });
  }

  onChangeDate(date) {
    this.setState({
      date: date
    });
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ride = {
      username: this.state.username,
      description: this.state.description,
      duration: this.state.duration,
      distance: this.state.distance,
      date: this.state.date
    };

    console.log(ride);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/rides/add', ride)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    window.location = '/';
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>Create New Ride Log</h3>
        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Username: </label>
            <select ref="userInput"
              required
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.username}
              onChange={this.onChangeUsername}>
              {
                this.state.users.map(function (user) {
                  return <option
                    key={user}
                    value={user}>{user}
                  </option>;
                })
              }
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Description: </label>
            <input type="text"
              required
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.description}
              onChange={this.onChangeDescription}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Duration (in minutes): </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.duration}
              onChange={this.onChangeDuration}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Distance (in miles): </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="form-control"
              value={this.state.distance}
              onChange={this.onChangeDistance}
            />
          </div>
          <div className="form-group">
            <label>Date: </label>
            <div>
              <DatePicker
                selected={this.state.date}
                onChange={this.onChangeDate}
              />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create Ride Log" className="btn btn-primary" />
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The code I am targeting is in the ComponentDidMount() {...} mapping the user and usernames to state, and then again later down below in the html render.

What I have now as a functional component looks like this:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import DatePicker from 'react-datepicker';
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";

const CreateRide = (props) => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [description, setDescription] = useState('');
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [distance, setDistance] = useState(0);
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:5000/users/');
      if (response.data.length > 0) {
        setUsers({ users: response.data.map(user => user.username ) });
        setUsername({ username: response.data[0].username });
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    setUsername(e.target.value);
  }
  const onChangeDescription = (e) => {
    setDescription(e.target.value);
  }
  const onChangeDuration = (e) => {
    setDuration(e.target.value);
  }
  const onChangeDistance = (e) => {
    setDistance(e.target.value);
  }
  const onChangeDate = (date) => {
    setDate(date);
  }
  const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const ride = {
      username: username,
      description: description,
      duration: duration,
      distance: distance,
      date: date
    };

    console.log(ride);

    axios.post('http://localhost:5000/rides/add', ride)
      .then(res => console.log(res.data));

    window.location = '/';
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Create New Ride Log</h3>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Username: </label>
          <select
            required
            className="form-control"
            value={username}
            onChange={onChangeUsername}>
            {
              users.map(user => {
                return <option key={user} value={user}>{user}</option>;
              })
            }
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Description: </label>
          <input type="text"
            required
            className="form-control"
            value={description}
            onChange={onChangeDescription}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Duration (in minutes): </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={duration}
            onChange={onChangeDuration}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Distance (in miles): </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="form-control"
            value={distance}
            onChange={onChangeDistance}
          />
        </div>
        <div className="form-group">
          <label>Date: </label>
          <div>
            <DatePicker
              selected={date}
              onChange={onChangeDate}
            />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="submit" value="Create Ride Log" className="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}


export default CreateRide;
```

Here is what a sample json response looks like when I run it through postman:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "5f39e38abfa99e273e299fd8",
        "username": "Rudy",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-17T01:55:22.797Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T01:55:22.797Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "5f39e391bfa99e273e299fd9",
        "username": "James",
        "createdAt": "2020-08-17T01:55:29.727Z",
        "updatedAt": "2020-08-17T01:55:29.727Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {...}
]
```

Further on down in the HTML, I am struggling to conceptualize how the ref='userInput' is being used in the first  form-group. Using a functional component creates an error of not allowing strings refs.

I know that this encompasses more than one question, but I'm pretty jammed up and anything would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions in order:

**1. User data:** You're setting your user data in objects:

```
setUsers({ users: response.data.map(user => user.username ) });
setUsername({ username: response.data[0].username });
```

That should just be:

```
setUsers(response.data.map(user => user.username));
setUsername(response.data[0].username);
```

**2. Refs:** It doesn't look like you're using that ref in the original class-based code, you should be able to remove it. If you do need a ref to the `select` element, you can use the `useRef` hook, documentation here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

Comment: I hadn't touched this project in a day or so because I was getting frustrated with this roadblock. Thanks so much for the help! You really unjammed me.

Comment: Happy to hear it!